# Capturing multiple instances of a subgroup

Tags: regex, regex-group

I try to capture the different values each of a survey's variables can take by extracting  value labels from a data dictionary. These are formatted as follows:

```
value AGEGRP_
 1 = "0 to 9 years"
 2 = "10 to 14 years"
 3 = "20 years and over"
 88 = "Not available"
;
```

What I want to obtain is the following:

```
Group 1: AGEGRP (note: without underscore)
Group 2: 1
Group 3: 0 to 9 years
Group 4: 2
Group 5: 10 to 14 years
Group 6: 3
Group 7: 20 years and over
Group 8: 88
Group 9: Not available
```

Of course, the number of value labels will vary for each variable.

Using regex101.com, I have built the following expression:

```
value (.+)_(?:\R|\z)((\s(.+) = "(.+)"(?:\R|\z))+);
```

My function:

```
parse_sas_variable_labels <- function(text) {
 pattern <- "value (.+)_(?:\\R|\\z)((\\s(.+) = \"(.+)\"(?:\\R|\\z))+);"
 l <- str_match_all(text, pattern) # to extract all patterns on the same line 
 df <- map_dfr(l, ~ tibble(var = .x[,2], label = .x[,3]))
 return(df) 
}
```

This does not quite work: it gives me

```
Group 1.    AGEGRP
Group 2.    1 = "0 to 9 years"
            2 = "10 to 14 years"
            3 = "20 years and over"
            88 = "Not available"
Group 3.    88 = "Not available"
Group 4.    88
Group 5.    Not available
```

Only groups 1, 4 and 5 correspond to some of what I want; but then, it only returns the **last** iteration of the value labels that it finds and *omits* those for ages 0-10, 10-19, and 20+. The explanation seems to be, according to regex101.com:

> A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a
> capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or
> use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data

How should I correct my expression?

Comment: It will be generally difficult to get each key/value into a separate capture group in a single match, partly because you might not know a priori how many lines your input text file would have.  What _tool_ are you using with your regex engine?  In something like Python or PHP, this would be pretty easy to parse.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use R, with the stringr library.

Comment: Is the input a file, string, vector of strings, something else?  Can you include sample R code?

Comment: This is the function that I seek to build:

parse_sas_variable_labels <- function(text) {
  
  pattern <- "MY_REGEX"
  l <- str_match_all(text, pattern) # to extract all patterns on the same line
  df <- map_dfr(l, ~ tibble(var = .x[,2], label = .x[,3]))
  return(df)
}

Comment: # This function (1) takes a pattern in a SAS file associating each variable 
  # name with its label;
  # (2) return the matches in each line as a list; and
  # (3) transforms this list into a dataframe

Comment: The input is a character vector. A SAS script is read from a file, returning a character vector ("text").

Comment: Please include R code which defines this vector, to make your question _reproducible_.

Comment: This is the best regex I could come with: [please check](https://regex101.com/r/VHXIbp/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get repeated captures with the regex as you want, you will only capture the last value.

Capture all the lines with assignment with

```
value (.+)_((?:\R\s.+ = ".+")+)\s*;
```

Then, extract the keys and values separately from Group 2:

```
(?m)^\h*(.+?)\h*=\h*"(.+)"
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/KwTkRm/1)

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?m)                     set flags for this block (with ^ and $
                           matching start and end of line) (case-
                           sensitive) (with . not matching \n)
                           (matching whitespace and # normally)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \h*                      horizontal whitespace (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .+?                      any character except \n (1 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \h*                      horizontal whitespace (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  =                        '='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \h*                      'h' (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
```